# Display an alert box with line-breaks in for loop dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

here I want one row then line break then another row and so on.... in only one alert message...

```
function GetCellValues()
{
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     var str = '';
    for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
    {
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
        for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)

        {
            str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
        }

    }
    alert(str);
}
```

Comment: use `\n` for new line. e.g. `alert('1\n2')` will show 1 and 2 in separate lines

Answer (score 2):

Use a newline character: **\n**

```
function GetCellValues()
{
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     var str = '';
    for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
    {
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
        for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)

        {
            str += inputs[k].value + '\n';
        }

    }
    alert(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this as you want line breaks for each row.we have add line breaks in outer for loop

```
function GetCellValues()
{
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     var str = '';
    for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
    {
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
        for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)

        {
            str += inputs[k].value + ',';
        }
       str += inputs[k].value + '\n';
    }
    alert(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use '\n' in place of ', '